# MD5 convert and convert it back in text

Tags: c#, encryption, md5

i want to save password s in database encrypted in md5
How to convert text into md5 with c# and convert it back in text?

Thanks

Comment: Please add more context to your question - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Running text through a MD5 hashing method is not encrypting it. A value ran through a MD5 hashing method is one way. Without the original text there isn't a way to get the original value unless you try every possible combination. DO NOT STORE passwords with a simple MD5 hash, its really not secure, and extremely easy to brute force.

Comment: If it wasn't for the fact this post may server as a warning to others i'd flag it!

Answer (score 10):

[Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is not [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) - it is not reversible.

Comment: I want to point out that it is not supposed to be reversible. Everyone knows that some hashing methods, like md5, are really easy to decipher and thus reversible. If you meant that the algorithm doesn't allow it to be reversible then you are correct.

Comment: @Rutix - Rainbow tables are lookups and thus _some_ MD5 hashes become "reversible". And even then, if you add a few special characters that are outside the values most rainbow tables are generated for, you are safe.

Comment: Yes I know and you are correct. I just wanted to point out that it depends on what you define as reversible :).

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to convert back to the original password. If you want to check the user has entered the correct password you should hash their attempt and compare that hashed value to the hashed value in the database. At no point will the plaintext password be compared to anything.

Comment: You forgot to point out he should not be using MD5 to encrypt/hash passwords.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use MD5 for hashing passwords, it is very insecure. What you should do is use a user specific salt and maybe 3 different hashing algorithms that take at least 1 second to run. It may seem like 1 second is a long time but that is the point. You user only has to log into the site once and a cracker will have to spend one minute trying just 60 different passwords. Personally I use a site specific salt and user specific salts. That way if my database were compromised they would still be missing a some of the pieces to crack the passwords.

Comment: In order to have a user specfic salt it would have to be based on the user's details.  There is no reason to run the same value through 3 different hashing alorithms.  A far better solution would be to use an encryption algorithm.  Otherwise your suggestion about using a unique salt for each user is valid.

Comment: Why would it have to be based on the user's details? You could create a GUID when a user registers or as I do on my PHP sites use Linux's urandom to create a user salt. You don't need 3 hashing algorithms but I do it to make it more processor intensive when running it through my loop.

Comment: Making the hash slow sucks up your own server resources.  If you're protecting against someone hacking from outside your site, a delayed response (perhaps graduated based on number of attempts) will accomplish the same thing.  The purpose of making your hash function expensive is in case the hacker actually gets *into* your server...I'd prefer 0.1s to 1.0s for usability reasons, since there's a law of diminishing returns when brute-forcing user-passwords such that 1.0s and 0.1s aren't very different in terms of hacker benefit, but are still significant to your user.

Answer (score 0):

Saving a hash of a password is not saving a password - you can't get a password back out of it. One way only. Otherwise it would be called encryption.

You are saving something which you can compare against a hash of another password typed in later. If the two hashes are the same, the password is the same (well, incredibly unlikely to be anything else - exclude hash collisions as being less likely than [Gorillas](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1172/411) for good hashing algorithms using a big enough space)

You can look at this discussion on [salting vs multiple hashes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/760/411) over at Crypto SE.